# typescript - get the day name from a date

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried to get the day name from a date, but with the date `27/02/2021` i get Invalid Date

```
new Date(exam.examDate).toLocaleString('fr-FR', { weekday: 'long' })
```

i tried to convert the date using datePipe but it return the below error

> Unable to convert "27/02/2021" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe

```
new Date(this.datePipe.transform(exam.examDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")).toLocaleString('fr-FR', { weekday: 'long' })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a custom day name from `Date` like:

```js
const names = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const dayName = names[dateObject.getDay()];
```

```js
const date = '27/02/2021';
const d = date.split('/');
const names = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const dayName = names[new Date(d[2],d[1],d[0]).getDay()];
console.log(dayName);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Date` expects `MM/DD/YYYY` but you're passing `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```js
const getDay = date => {
  const parts = date.split('/');
  return new Date(+parts[2], +parts[1] - 1, +parts[0]).toString().split(' ')[0]; 
}

console.log( getDay('27/02/2021') );
```

Using `moment.js`:

```js
const getDay = date =>
  moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('ddd');

console.log( getDay('27/02/2021') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: `new Date(...)` accepts other formats, not only "MM/DD/YYYY" — I prefer international format "YYYY-MM-DD", or as ISO with a time "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS"

Answer (score 1):

```js
examDate = "27/02/2021";
date = examDate.split("/");
x = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0]);

// it prints "samedi"
console.log(x.toLocaleString('fr-FR', { weekday: 'long' }));
```